# Mongoose field validation not working correctly

Tags: node.js, validation, mongoose

I'm using the library `validator` to validate the Dates in my Mongoose Schemas.

I have the following code:

```
var validator = require('validator');

var TesteSchema = new Schema({
  testeData: { type: Date, required: true, validate: validator.isISO8601}
```

Since Mongoose saves Dates in the ISO8601 format, I'm validating it accordingly. But the problem is the validation is returning false, even when I provide it with a valid ISO Date.

Comment: The validator function expects a `string` but mongoose has already cast the value to a `date` by the time the validator is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment: "The validator function expects a `string` but Mongoose has already cast the value to a `date` by the time the validator is executed."

See the following code below to see this happening:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const TesteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  testeData: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
    validate: (v) => v instanceof Date
  }
});
const Teste = mongoose.model('Teste', TesteSchema);

const teste = new Teste({
  testeData: '11/11/2018'
});

teste.validate(); // true
```

#### Update

One approach to validate the string input is to store the value as a string and if necessary to also have a date version then a setter can be used to store this value to another property to be stored.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const validator = require('validator');

const TesteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  testeData: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    validate: validator.isISO8601,
    set: function (d) { return this._testeData = d; }
  },
  _testeData: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
  }
});
const Teste = mongoose.model('Teste', TesteSchema);

const testeBad = new Teste({
  testeData: '11/11/2018'
});
console.log(testeBad);
/*
{
  _id: ObjectId('5aeb55c58e374e7034c8a1bb'),
  _testeData: IsoDate('Sun Nov 11 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)'),
  testeData: '11/11/2018'
}
*/
testeBad.validate(); // Teste validation failed: testeData: Validator failed for path `testeData` with value `11/11/2018`

const testeGood = new Teste({
  testeData: '2018-11-11T00:00:00'
});
console.log(testeGood);
/*
{
  _id: ObjectId('5aeb55c58e374e7034c8a1bc'),
  _testeData: IsoDate('Sun Nov 11 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)'),
  testeData: '2018-11-11T00:00:00'
}
*/
testeGood.validate(); // true
```

Comment: That makes sense. How would you then suggest I go about verifying if the Date object is indeed a valid ISO Date? Maybe use a String instead of a Date for the field type? Or maybe leave it as a Date but validate it with some other function?

Comment: Depends on what the concern is. If it is to ensure the string provided will parse to a valid date, then the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor accepts as a date string value anything in either the ISO8601 or RFC 2822 (but there are caveats - read the note on `dateString` arguments). This is what mongoose is doing automatically. If it is to restrict it beyond that then one approach is to save the string as a `String` type and validate as you were. See update.